# A service worker with different scope from that of a page

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I was wondering if I am able to install a service-worker with scope different to that of a page (it wants to serve) but same scope to the resources it's proxying.

I am interested in this setup as I want my service-worker to control URLs under `/resources/` and not interfere with other URLs. There is another service-worker registered in the root which I don't control.

Here is the structure of my example:

```
/page/index.html
/resources/sw.js
/resources/a
/resources/b
/resources/c
```

The page in `/page/index.html` registers the service-worker as

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/resources/sw.js', {scope: '/resources/'})
            .then((reg) => {
                console.log('service-worker registration success: scope=' + reg.scope);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('service-worker registration failure: error=' + error);
            });
    });
}
```

When the page fetches url from the `/resources/` path I want my service-worker to intercept these urls. Unfortunately the setup doesn't work. `/page/index.html` is not controlled by the service-worker.

I know that if I change the scope of the worker (using the Service-Worker-Allowed or moving the file) to `/page/` I will be able to control all fetches for `/page/index.html` but as I said I don't control any other paths apart from `/resources/`

Finally is there a solution to implement what I want without interfering with the root service-worker?

Comment: register('./page/resources/sw.js'   -  have you tried that?

Comment: Hi, I am not able to do this. I don't have access to /page path only to /resources

Comment: Hi @Kostas did you end up finding a solution for this?